# Print a PDF in printer using Java and 3rd party lib in Solaris OS

Tags: java, pdf, open-source, solaris, solaris-10

I wrote an application to print a PDF file using Java with PDFBox or itext. I ran the program in windows it worked perfectly. But I faced some problems when i ran the same program in Solaris OS. Seams PDFBOx and itext are not supporting in Solaris OS. Its not giving any error message but its not printing the PDF file.  Can any one suggest me some free third party library? I'm try this more than two week. It really appreciate, if i get any help for this. Many thanks

Comment: *Seams PDFBOx and itext are not functioning properly in Solaris OS.* - As printing PDFs is not an iText feature, not printing on Solaris is **not** a sign of *not functioning properly*. That being said, it looks like you are using at least iText for something else and, therefore, should explain your use case more in detail.

Answer (score 0):

It seems [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) is widely popular java library for printing PDF, works everywhere on Java.

Comment: Widely popular for creatingand manipulating pdfs, not for printing.

Comment: @k.honsali well, its not working in Solaris  OS. If work i wont publish this question here.